# drupal form action

Tags: php, forms, drupal

I've create a form like:

```
function create_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['#action'] = "#";
        ....
}

function create_custom_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
        ....
}

function create_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
        ....
        if(..)
           drupal_goto('abc');
        else
           drupal_goto('xxx');
}
```

when i submit this form drupal before go to action and after read my function... how I can bypass the action-form and read only a _submit function?

Comment: add handler to your submit button by `$form['submit'] = array('create_custom_form_submit');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use **[drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)** as there may be more "submit" callbacks to execute. The [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) function will interrupt these.

Instead, use the `$form_state['redirect'] = ...`
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7

```php
function create_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
        ....
        if(..)
           $form_state['redirect'] = 'abc';
        else
           $form_state['redirect'] = 'xxx';
}
```

As this function has the same form ID (`create_custom_form`) - with the word "_submit" appended then this function will be executed automatically and so there is no need to add any submit callbacks into the form.

If you want an additional function to execute on submit then you should do as Hamza has suggested, only your additional function will have a different name. e.g.

```php
function create_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#action'] = "#";
  ....
  // Add any additional callbacks to call before any redirects happen
  $form['#submit'][] = 'create_custom_form_additional_submit_callback';    
  $form['#submit'][] = ...
}

function create_custom_form_additional_submit_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  // Do something before redirect
  ...
}
```

In the above example:

- `create_custom_form_additional_submit_callback`

**AND**

- `create_custom_form_submit` (because its got the same name with '_submit' appended)

will execute and only when they have both finished will the redirect be executed.

Comment: I've try whit $form_state['redirect'] but I've the same problem... if I change the form action whit a fake-page drupal redirect in this fake-page and not follow the redirect or goto... I think before goto action and after check _submit...

Comment: If you set the form action to a hash "#" the page will submit to itself however the server and drupal will never see your "#", even though its in the URL it is not a visible character to your server. As Drupal is looking for a # it will never find, your submit hooks will never fire. If your looking to detect if the form was submitted by other scripts on your page then why not set the action to something like "?submitted=1"